# Switch 2960, Router 2901, Layer 3 switch 3560 manual reboot query

Tags: switch, router

I'm learning networking. I had however a doubt is there a way to manually reboot the above switches and routers besides the command line? By maybe unplugging and plugging the equipment quickly or a reboot button anywhere on the equipment?

Thanks

Comment: Unplugging the devices will certainly reboot them.  I don't have these devices handy to check, but if memory serves, they do not have a reset button.

Comment: There are no reset button on any of the switches.

Comment: @Cown: There is the "mode" button on the access switch class devices (2960 series and others). Pressed after power-on, the the mode button will drop the console to the boot prompt. Depending on previous configuration of _service password-recovery, the switch will then allow to boot without reading `startup-config` (when _on_), hence no password is active and it may be reset, or (when _off_) will erase `startup-config` and `vlan.dat`, which brings the thing pretty close to a "reset feature".

Comment: And the 3750X take it even a step further: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/hardware/installation/guide/3750x_3560x_HIG/HGTRBL.html#wp1060415
Here, keeping the button pressed for 10 seconds or longer will reboot the switch with a blanked configuration.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi, in the context of the OP question, reset as in reboot. Yes, the mode button can be used on many platforms (if not disabled) to factory reset a Cisco Catalyst access device. But no way to simply restart it.

Comment: @YLearn agreed. Terms are getting a bit fuzzy. OP asks for reboot feature,  Cown answers and comments using the term "reset button". I would postulate that most implementations of "reset buttons" across the world of electronics are of the "factory reset" variety, not the "reboot" kind.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi, I find a lot of networking equipment that use the term "reset" for a reboot. I was just in a Radware ADC today and their terminology for a reboot is "reset."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco has always been known to not include any on/off or reset buttons on any of their switching equipment. The only way, besides the CLI (Command Line Interface), to restart or reset your switch is to disconnect the power and reconnect it again.

All Cisco equipment is made from military grade parts, though some will argue, that the quality over time has deteriorated. But it will definitely not take any damaged from a hard power unplug reset.

The routers on the other hand, can have an on/off button, but it depends a lot on the model.

Comment: Years ago, I was tasked to go to a site in the middle of the night where the power would be cut while the utility company worked on the circuits. It would be down for a few hours. The request was that I properly shut down the switches. I tried to explain that you just pull the power cables, but they insisted that I needed to get into the switches to run a "shutdown" command so that they would be properly shutdown. I again explained that there was no such thing, but they made me go up there anyway. I just yanked the power cords. They were shocked and reported me to my manager, who laughed.

Comment: @RonMaupin LOL well how stupid is that... :D

Comment: What can you expect from server guys...

Comment: Very true, but i still think it's funny, that almost all other manufacturers of network equipment include a on/off button.

Comment: @Cown, I can't think of many network switches in my experience (enterprise, smb or consumer) that have had an on/off button/switch. Routers are more likely to have them, but still often do not.

Comment: @YLearn thanks, that is why i edited the post and corrected it to switching equipment and added the last section regarding routers. Initially by my comment, i was also only referencing the switches, as i had them all available to look at, when writing it.